# Parsing XML containing name space

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, plsql, xml-parsing

I am having problems with parsing XML containing name-space.

This is my XML structure (snipped, with modified data):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.053.001.02" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.053.001.02 ./camt.053.001.02.xsd">
    <BkToCstmrStmt>
        <Stmt>
            <Ntry>
                <Amt Ccy="EUR">0.0</Amt>
                <CdtDbtInd>CCCC</CdtDbtInd>
                <Sts>BBBB</Sts>
                <BookgDt>
                    <Dt>2011-01-01</Dt>
                </BookgDt>
                <ValDt>
                    <Dt>2011-01-01</Dt>
                </ValDt>
                <AcctSvcrRef>325569685ASDAS</AcctSvcrRef>
                <BkTxCd>
                    <Prtry>
                        <Cd>NOTPROVIDED</Cd>
                    </Prtry>
                </BkTxCd>
                <NtryDtls>
                    <TxDtls>
                        <Refs>
                            <EndToEndId>DD545454545-54545-54</EndToEndId>
                            <TxId>46545445G5GG54DD5S</TxId>
                        </Refs>
                        <RltdPties>
                            <Dbtr>
                                <Nm>TEST</Nm>
                                <PstlAdr>
                                    <Ctry>JJ</Ctry>
                                    <AdrLine>TEST ADD</AdrLine>
                                    <AdrLine>TEST ADD2</AdrLine>
                                </PstlAdr>
                            </Dbtr>
                            <DbtrAcct>
                                <Id>
                                    <IBAN>000000000000000</IBAN>
                                </Id>
                            </DbtrAcct>
                            <Cdtr>
                                <Nm>TEST NAME</Nm>
                                <PstlAdr>
                                    <Ctry>JJ</Ctry>
                                    <AdrLine>TEST ADD3</AdrLine>
                                    <AdrLine>TEST ADD4</AdrLine>
                                </PstlAdr>
                            </Cdtr>
                            <CdtrAcct>
                                <Id>
                                    <IBAN>22222222222222</IBAN>
                                </Id>
                            </CdtrAcct>
                        </RltdPties>
                        <Purp>
                            <Cd>IIII</Cd>
                        </Purp>
                        <RmtInf>
                            <Strd>
                                <CdtrRefInf>
                                    <Ref>GG56565656565656</Ref>
                                </CdtrRefInf>
                                <AddtlRmtInf>TEST TEST 123</AddtlRmtInf>
                            </Strd>
                        </RmtInf>
                        <RltdDts>
                            <IntrBkSttlmDt>2011-01-01</IntrBkSttlmDt>
                        </RltdDts>
                    </TxDtls>
                </NtryDtls>
            </Ntry>
        </Stmt>
    </BkToCstmrStmt>
</Document>
```

This is the code i use that works if root element is without namespace ():

```
DECLARE       
      l_clob CLOB;
      l_bfile  BFILE := BFILENAME('XML_IMPORT', 'test_import.xml');
      l_dest_offset   INTEGER := 1;
      l_src_offset    INTEGER := 1;
      l_bfile_csid    NUMBER  := 0;
      l_lang_context  INTEGER := 0;
      l_warning       INTEGER := 0;
      l_xml           xmltype;
BEGIN
      DBMS_LOB.createtemporary (l_clob, TRUE);
      DBMS_LOB.fileopen(l_bfile, DBMS_LOB.file_readonly);

      DBMS_LOB.loadclobfromfile (
        dest_lob      => l_clob,
        src_bfile     => l_bfile,
        amount        => DBMS_LOB.lobmaxsize,
        dest_offset   => l_dest_offset,
        src_offset    => l_src_offset,
        bfile_csid    => l_bfile_csid ,
        lang_context  => l_lang_context,
        warning       => l_warning);
      DBMS_LOB.fileclose(l_bfile);          

      l_xml := xmltype(l_clob);

     BEGIN
      FOR r IN (
        SELECT ExtractValue(Value(p),'/Ntry/Amt/text()') as TEMP_COL1
              ,ExtractValue(Value(p),'/Ntry/Amt/@Ccy/text()') as TEMP_COL2
              ,ExtractValue(Value(p),'/Ntry/ValDt/Dt/text()') as TEMP_COL3
              ,ExtractValue(Value(p),'/Ntry/BookgDt/Dt/text()') as TEMP_COL4

        FROM    TABLE(XMLSequence(Extract(l_xml,'/Document/BkToCstmrStmt/Stmt/Ntry'))) p
        ) 
        LOOP
            dbms_output.put_line('Some value 1: ' ||  r.TEMP_COL1);
            dbms_output.put_line('Some value 2: ' ||  r.TEMP_COL2);
            dbms_output.put_line('Some value 3: ' ||  r.TEMP_COL3);
            dbms_output.put_line('Some value 4: ' ||  r.TEMP_COL4);
        END LOOP;
    END;     
END;
```

I would like to know how to modify my code to work with name space.
Google provided few examples but so far i had no luck implementing them into my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to pass the namespace to both the `Extract()` and `ExtractValue()` functions e.g.

```
FOR r IN (
    SELECT ExtractValue(Value(p),'/Ntry/Amt/text()', 'xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.053.001.02"') as TEMP_COL1
          ,ExtractValue(Value(p),'/Ntry/Amt/@Ccy','xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.053.001.02"') as TEMP_COL2
          ,ExtractValue(Value(p),'/Ntry/ValDt/Dt/text()','xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.053.001.02"') as TEMP_COL3
          ,ExtractValue(Value(p),'/Ntry/BookgDt/Dt/text()','xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.053.001.02"') as TEMP_COL4

    FROM    TABLE(XMLSequence(Extract(l_xml,'/Document/BkToCstmrStmt/Stmt/Ntry', 'xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.053.001.02"'))) p
  ) 
  LOOP
      dbms_output.put_line('Some value 1: ' ||  r.TEMP_COL1);
      dbms_output.put_line('Some value 2: ' ||  r.TEMP_COL2);
      dbms_output.put_line('Some value 3: ' ||  r.TEMP_COL3);
      dbms_output.put_line('Some value 4: ' ||  r.TEMP_COL4);
  END LOOP;
```

I don't think there is a way to specify a default namespace for the `ExtractValue` function, so my personal preference would be to do something like this instead which avoids repeatedly declaring the namespace:

```
FOR r IN (
    SELECT p.temp_col1,
           p.temp_col2,
           p.temp_col3,
           p.temp_col4
    FROM   xmltable(
             --define a default namespace to be used for all values
             xmlnamespaces(
               DEFAULT 'urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.053.001.02'
             ),

             --define an xpath expression for the values you want to extract
             '/Document/BkToCstmrStmt/Stmt/Ntry'

             --pass the xml type in here
             PASSING l_xml

             --declare the columns you would like to extract and the formats they are expected to be in
             COLUMNS
               temp_col1 VARCHAR2(128) path '/Ntry/Amt/text()',
               temp_col2 VARCHAR2(128) path '/Ntry/Amt/@Ccy',
               temp_col3 VARCHAR2(128) path '/Ntry/ValDt/Dt/text()',
               temp_col4 VARCHAR2(128) path '/Ntry/BookgDt/Dt/text()'
           ) p
  )
  LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line('Some value 1: ' ||  r.temp_col1);
    dbms_output.put_line('Some value 2: ' ||  r.temp_col2);
    dbms_output.put_line('Some value 3: ' ||  r.temp_col3);
    dbms_output.put_line('Some value 4: ' ||  r.temp_col4);
  END LOOP;
```